# picture update before old picture delete after update new picture php

Tags: php

I am using PHP 7.2 update picture table name banner and field id, image, posted,update_date.
i have to need oldfile file is deleted after update new file  its possible than help me please I am share php code , database and html form here...

**table name is banner**

> Database like this

```
id |  image           | posted       | update_date

  1|  amit-1234.jpg   | 05/06/2019   | 06/06/2019

  2|  amit-1254.jpg   | 05/06/2019   | 06/06/2019

  3|  ravi-1236.jpg   | 05/06/2019   | 06/06/2019

  4|  mohan-1274.jpg  | 05/06/2019   | 06/06/2019
```

**UPdate pictute PHP script**

```
 <?php 

    $msg='';

    if(isset($_POST['update'])){

    $banner_id= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['banner_id']);

    $update_date   = date('d-m-y');

    $sql9 = "SELECT * FROM banner WHERE banner_id='$banner_id'";

    $result9 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql9);

    mysqli_num_rows($result9) > 0;

    $row9 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result9);

    if(!empty($_FILES['image'] ['name'])){ 

    $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['image'] ['name']);

    $origname= $extension[0];

    $image = $origname . '-' .rand(10000,99999) . '.' . $extension[1];

    $file_loc1 = $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];

    $folder1="vendors/banner/";

    $dir="vendors/banner/"; //error this part is not workiing

    unlink($dir.'/'.$folder1);//error this part is not workiing

    move_uploaded_file($file_loc1,$folder1.$image);


    } else{$image=$row9['image'];}

    $sql = "UPDATE banner SET image='$image',update_date='$update_date' where 
     banner_id='$banner_id'";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    $msg="Successfully Updated your Banner Thank You ";


     }

     } 

    ?>
```

**HTML form**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <div class="form-group">

    <label >BANNER IMAGE :</label>
    <div><center><img src="vendors/banner/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" style="width:100%;   height:108px;"></center></div><br>

    <input class="form-control form-control-lg p-0" type="file" name="image" value="<?php echo $row['image'];?>" >

</div>
 <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-info">UPDATE BANNER</button>

</form>
```

Comment: I don't see any code there that would delete a file, so is your question what function can you use to do so? If so, [unlink](http://php.net/unlink).

Comment: I have no idea using this function but using unlike the script but ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what your comment is saying.

Comment: again check PHP script unlink code sir

Comment: You need to unlink the old file right? Not the directory. So the arg you pass into unlink needs to be the file path which you can build from the directory object you have, and the database row you selected.

Comment: yes sir but how please edit this code and share me